# What parser generator does Dart use?

Tags: dart, parser-generator

I see in the "analyzer_experimental" package of dartlang, there are some generated dart code for parsers:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/?r=24255#dart%2Fpkg%2Fanalyzer_experimental%2Flib%2Fsrc%2Fgenerated

I wonder what parser generator it uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [README](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/pkg/analyzer_experimental/README.md?r=24255), it looks like it's not generated by a parser generator, but rather machine-translated from an existing (presumably human-coded) Java implementation:

> **This code is part of an experimental port of the Editor's analysis engine from
>   Java to Dart.** While we will continue to support the Java version of the analysis
>   engine and the services built on it, we also intend to provide the same services
>   to Dart-based applications. This is very early code and we expect it to change,
>   possibly in significant ways. While we are eager to see other people make use
>   of the analysis engine, we also want to be clear, in case you are interested in
>   doing so, that the current API's should in no way be considered to be stable.
>
> **In particular, this code was automatically translated from the Java
>   implementation. The Java implementation that was translated is still under
>   development and will continue to change over time. The translator that was used
>   is still under development** and the output produced by the translator will change
>   over time. Therefore, the API presented by this code will change. In addition,
>   any edits made to this code will be overwritten the next time we re-generate
>   this code.
>
> If you are interested in using this code, despite the disclaimer above,
>   fantastic! Please let the editor team know so that we can get a sense of the
>   interest in it. Also, feel free to ask questions and make requests for
>   additional functionality.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Then, what's parser generator the java version uses?